# How to find all words that match a regex?

Tags: python, regex

This might have been asked before, but, I am unable to find a solution. Suppose my text is `'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /v /c hello cmd.exe'` and I want to find and remove all words that has the regex `r'cmd.exe'`. The result must be: `'/v /c hello'`.

This is what I tried: First, I tried to find the indices of the words-boundaries so that I can remove them. But, the indices I got was for the exact regular-expression...not for the whole matching word.

```
In [41]: [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'\b\w*cmd.exe\w*\b', cmd)]
Out[41]: [(20, 27), (40, 47)]

In [42]: [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'cmd.exe', cmd)]
Out[42]: [(20, 27), (40, 47)]

In [44]: result = re.findall(r'cmd.exe', cmd, re.I)

In [45]: result
Out[45]: ['cmd.exe', 'cmd.exe']. <-- I wanted ['C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'cmd.exe']

In [48]: result = re.findall(r'cmd.exe|\bcmd.exe\b', cmd, re.I)

In [49]: result
Out[49]: ['cmd.exe', 'cmd.exe']
```

In short, how to get the whole word(s) that contains the substring/regex?

Comment: `\w` only matches letters, digits and underscores (and some other rare chars in Python 3.x), you can't expect it to match ``\`` or `:`. Use `[\w:\\]*` to match them all.

Comment: Right. I realized that mistake and then tried \b...but, no luck.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion...and it worked.In [51]: [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'\b[\w:\\]*cmd.exe[\w:\\]*\b', cmd)]
Out[51]: [(0, 27), (40, 47)]

Comment: Matching paths with regex is actually a very difficult thing since they may contain whitespaces. There is no 100% safe regex to match them.

Answer (score 3):

Not saying regex is bad*, but why not simply:

```
txt = 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /v /c hello cmd.exe'
outcome = ' '.join([part for part in txt.split(' ') if not 'cmd.exe' in part])
```

which gives:

```
'/v /c hello'
```

*<sub>Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.</sub>

Comment: I like your no-nonsense, easy-to-understand approach.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```
>>> s = r'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /v /c hello cmd.exe'
>>> print (re.sub(r'\S*cmd\.exe\S*\s*', '', s))
/v /c hello
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `'\S*`: Match 0 or more non-whitespace characters
- `cmd\.exe`: Match `cmd.exe`
- `\S*`: Match 0 or more non-whitespace characters
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespace characters

Comment: This will only work for the file path in the question. If a folder or file contains a whitespace (which is a usual thing), this won't work.

Comment: Agreed but even though inout looks like a path but OP just mentioned it being a `text` and no where it is mentioned that search string may contain whitespaces.